# How to take a Screenshot of a View and insert the Picture into a MS-Word Document

Tags: c++, view, mfc, ms-word

I'm using `MFC` under `vs2010`, and I want to save `the view` display as `a picture`, then insert `the picture` into `a document in MS-WORD format`. But few `APIs` or `Documents` can I find. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You are likely to get more helpful answers if you say what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roughly along this line:

```
// Pick your own size of rectangle.
    CRect rect;
    GetWindowRect(&rect);    

    CDC memDC;
    memDC.CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);

    BITMAPINFO info;
    memset(&info, 0, sizeof(info));

// About the only parts of this you're likely to change 
// are the width and height.  You can change to fewer bits
// per pixel if you want -- doing so reduces file sizes,
// but increases headaches.  In a BMP file, each scan line 
// has to be DWORD aligned.  If you use 32 bit per pixel, 
// each pixel is a DWORD, so the alignment happens
// automatically.  Otherwise, you have to add padding as
// as needed, which is kind of a pain.
//
    info.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(info.bmiHeader);
    info.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    info.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 16;
    info.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    info.bmiHeader.biWidth = rect.Width();
    info.bmiHeader.biHeight = rect.Height();
    char *bits = NULL;

    HBITMAP section = CreateDIBSection(
        pDC->m_hDC,
        &info, 
        DIB_RGB_COLORS,
        (void **)&bits,
        NULL, 0);

    memDC.SelectObject(section);

// Draw something into the DIB.
    CBrush brush;
    brush.CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 255));

    CRect temp(0,0,rect.Width(), rect.Height());

    memDC.FillRect(temp, &brush);
    memDC.SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);
    memDC.SetTextColor(RGB(255, 0, 0));

// Copy the DIB to the screen, just because we can...
    pDC->BitBlt(0, 0, rect.Width(), rect.Height(), &memDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

// Ensure the GDI is done with anything it's doing
// with the DIB before we access the bits directly.
    GdiFlush();

    // Done drawing. Now save it:
    FILE *file = _wfopen(L"junk.bmp",L"wb");

    if ( NULL == file) 
        memDC.TextOut(0, 0, "File didn't open");
    else 
        memDC.TextOut(0, 0, "File opened");

// Get the size of the DIB, even though in this case
// we know it already because we just created it above.
    BITMAP object;
    GetObject(section, sizeof(object), &object);

    DWORD bit_size = object.bmWidthBytes * object.bmHeight;

    DWORD header_size = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER); 

// A BMP file header.  Pretty basic, really.
    BITMAPFILEHEADER header;
    memset(&header, 0, sizeof(header));
    header.bfType = 'MB';
    header.bfSize = bit_size + header_size;
    header.bfOffBits = header_size;

// Write out the file header.
    fwrite(&header, 1, sizeof(header), file);

// Write out the image header.
    fwrite(&info, 1, sizeof(info), file);

// write out the bits.
    fwrite(bits, 1, bit_size, file);

// and we're done.
    fclose(file);
```